# Is there a way to link two columns in two different tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I don't really know the terminology well enough to find anything on the subject.

Say I have two tables:

```
*Table 1*

[  id  |  username  |  first_name  | last_name  ]
```

and a second table

```
*Table 2*

[  id  |  username  |  age  ]
```

Is there a way to link the `username` columns from these two tables so that if I change a username in one table, the other table recognizes a match and also changes the username in its username column?

Example: So say in table 1 and table 2 theres a username `myUserName` (the rest of the row doesn't really matter).  Then, `myUserName` in table 1 gets changed to `theUserName`.  Is there a way to make it so that Table 2 sees this, and also changes its copy of `myUserName` to `theUserName`?

Comment: This seems to be a bad design. Why are there two tables at all? Why isn't "age" just a column in the first table?

Comment: You should read a bit on database design. That's the kind of problem that normalization tries to avoid.

Comment: @Vilx- But what if you need to store some data that you didn't forsee when you created the original table?  Is there some better way to handle this issue?  what would you recommend?

Comment: @piet.t Anything specific you can recommend?

Comment: @xcdemon05 - I would change the table and add that column.

Comment: This isn't necessarily bad design nor is it necessarily badly normalized.  If the username is a natural key and the two id columns are mutually independent then at worst we have redundant surrogate keys.  Changing an existing table could impact existing queries and code if they were poorly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first there is the topic of your design being a little less than optimal as stated in the comments to the question. However, assuming this is more of an example where you want to be able to update a value, you could use [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

```
alter table2 add foreign key (username) references table1 (username) on update cascade;
```

This will update table2 any time the value for table1 updates. For this example to work, I believe table1.username will have to be unique. If you have two records with the same username in table1 and edit it, table2 may see that it still has a valid key to reference and not change. (Though foreign keys in general don't need a unique index, just the way you would be wanting to use them.)

Comment: Columns referenced in a foreign key constraint don't have to have unique values (in MySQL, at least), but I think they must be indexed.  However, cascading updates in non-unique cases is likely to mean trouble.